# Taking the integral of one over x

Tags: integration

Given:
$$ \int\frac{1}{x}dx = \ln |\ x\ | +C $$

We have:
$$ 7\int\frac{1}{x}dx = 7\ln(x) + C $$
$$ \int\frac{1}{2x+4} = \frac{1}{2}\ln(2x+4) + C $$
$$ \int\frac{t}{t^{2}+4}dx = \frac{1}{2}\ln(t^{2}+4)+C $$
$$ \int\frac{3x-1}{9-2x+3x^{2}}dx = \frac{1}{2}\ln(9-2x+3x^{2})+C $$
$$ \int \cot(x)\ dx = \ln|\ \sin x\ |+C $$

Why does the absolute value in $ \int\frac{1}{x}dx = \ln |\ x\ | +C $ carry through to $ \int \cot(x)\ dx = \ln|\ \sin x\ |+C $, but not the other equalities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you should write the absolute value for all the equalities, for example we have

$$ \int\frac{dx}{2x+4} = \frac{1}{2}\ln(|2x+4|) + C $$
but since $t^2+4>0$ you can simply write
$$ \int\frac{t}{t^{2}+4}dt = \frac{1}{2}\ln(t^{2}+4)+C $$